# Add eventhandler to jQuery UI datepicker after its creation

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, datepicker, jquery-events, uidatepicker

I have the following scenario:

In my masterpage I have:

```
$(".datepicker").datepicker({
    changeYear: true,
    changeMonth: true,
    dateFormat: "dd/mm/yy",
    duration: 'fast'
});
```

With this, every input field that I assign the class "datepicker" to, shows the jQuery UI datepicker when clicked.

Now I have a datepicker on a page that should have its `onSelect` event handled. What would be the way considered best practise to do this?

Options I see:

- give that 1 datepicker another class, like `datepickerWithSelectEvent`. What I dont like about this solution is that I get duplicate code for initializing the `changeYear`, `changeMonth`, ... . If I want to change the datepickers in a project I'll have to remember changing this in 2 places
- Somehow add the eventhandler after the creation of the datepicker. This seems cleanest, but I don't really know how to do it. Anyone?

Answer (score 36, accepted):

Have you tried:

```
$(".datepickerSelect").datepicker( 'option' , 'onSelect', function() {} );
```

Comment: I knew it was something simple, didnt think about checking the regular jquery documentation.. thanks!