# onSelect event of DatePicker not rise

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have datepicker (Index.aspx):

```
<form class="fancy_form">
   <div class="wrap_input">
       <i>&nbsp;</i>
       <input type="text" class="datepicker"/>
    </div>
</form>
```

and js function (Index.aspx)

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
 $(".datepicker").datepicker({
            onSelect: function (dataText, inst) {
                loadFilmList(dataText);
            }
        });
    });
```

When I select date `loadFilmList` not call.

**One detail:**

There are `main.js` file where wrote:

```
jQuery(function($){
        $.datepicker.regional['ru'] = {
            closeText: 'Закрыть',
            prevText: '&#x3c;',
            nextText: '&#x3e;',
            currentText: 'Сегодня',
            monthNames: ['Январь','Февраль','Март','Апрель','Май','Июнь',
            'Июль','Август','Сентябрь','Октябрь','Ноябрь','Декабрь'],
            monthNamesShort: ['Янв','Фев','Мар','Апр','Май','Июн',
            'Июл','Авг','Сен','Окт','Ноя','Дек'],
            dayNames: ['воскресенье','понедельник','вторник','среда','четверг','пятница','суббота'],
            dayNamesShort: ['вск','пнд','втр','срд','чтв','птн','сбт'],
            dayNamesMin: ['Вс','Пн','Вт','Ср','Чт','Пт','Сб'],
            weekHeader: 'Не',
            dateFormat: 'dd.mm.yy',
            firstDay: 1,
            isRTL: false,
            showMonthAfterYear: false,
            yearSuffix: ''
        };
        $.datepicker.setDefaults($.datepicker.regional['ru']);
    });

$(function(){
        $(".datepicker").datepicker({
            showOn: "button",
            buttonImage: "/assets/images/calendar.png",
            buttonImageOnly: true
        });
});
```

**UPDATE:**
Ok, error was found, Thanks to Pencho.
But, I can't moving this block to `main.js`.
Question: How to add event handler after datepicker creation?

Thanks.

Comment: Any errors in your console? Have you tried Firebug and stepping through to see if the function is ever hit?

Comment: Your code works as you have written it for me: http://jsfiddle.net/aaAks/

Comment: on onSelect firebag stoping when page is loading, but when I select date  firebag not stoping on loadFilmList

Comment: Looks like you've been very thorough. Is loadFilmList defined in a visible scope? You might try replacing it with `alert('test')` or something.

Comment: your code seems correct to me. Try to check if onSelect function is being called, by putting an alert in onSelect function before calling loadFilmList.

Comment: I try replacing with alert("test") but window not show.

Comment: Ah ha, now that you've posted the rest of your code your error can be found. See Pencho's answer.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1204929/add-eventhandler-to-jquery-ui-datepicker-after-its-creation

Try this) there is better answer)

Comment: The  answer is here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1204929/add-eventhandler-to-jquery-ui-datepicker-after-its-creation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your main.js is creating the datepicker here:

```
$(function(){
        $(".datepicker").datepicker({
            showOn: "button",
            buttonImage: "/assets/images/calendar.png",
            buttonImageOnly: true
        });
});
```

Try moving your onSelect like so:

```
$(function(){
        $(".datepicker").datepicker({
            showOn: "button",
            buttonImage: "/assets/images/calendar.png",
            buttonImageOnly: true,
            onSelect: function (dataText, inst) {
                alert("a");
            }
        });
});
```

here is a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/YbzAT/)

Comment: If I moving there then loadFilmList I need to moving too

Answer (score 0):

Its just working fine. Keep the function `loadFilmList` inside `$(document).ready`.

check this fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/gG8ZQ/

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
 $(".datepicker").datepicker({
            onSelect: function (dataText, inst) {
                loadFilmList(dataText);
            }
        });

function loadFilmList(dataText){
    alert(dataText);
}
});
```